# Rotating recyclerView at it's position to 90 degrees

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have screen where upper half is covered with the cameraView and bottom half is a slidingPanel which contains a fragment and the fragment contains a recyclerView. I want the screen to be portrait only but when the orientation changes to landscape the object should rotate to 90 degrees at its position. I am rotating the FrameLayout which is containing the Fragment and which contains the RecyclerView. The object rotates perfectly but the problem is recyclerView is behaving very strange. When the frameLayout rotated to 90 degrees RecyclerView instead of scrolling vertically in landscape mode it is scrolling when scroll horizontally.

Below is my XML containing the FrameLayout which is been rotated to 90 degree.

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/layout_dragger"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
    app:ignore="NamespaceTypo"
    android:background="@color/transparent">

    <com.otaliastudios.cameraview.CameraView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        sothree:cameraFacing="front"
        sothree:cameraSessionType="video"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_dragger"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="68dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/up_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/up_arrow"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/record"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/record"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame_video"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp">
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Below is my Class which contains the rotating animation.

```
 public class MirrorFragment extends Fragment {

        private LinearLayout mQueen;
        private Button mHidden, accept, decline;
        private static final String TAG = "DemoActivity";
        private DraggingPanel mDraggingPanel;
        private LinearLayout mMainLayout;
        private FrameLayout frameContainer;
        Fragment childFragment;
        private Context mContext;
        int height,width;
        int draggingPanelHeight, draggingPanelWidth;
        private ImageView iv_record, up_arrow;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param;
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParam;
        SlidingUpPanelLayout mLayout;
        private Animation toLandAnim, toPortAnim;
        private OrientationListener orientationListener;
        private CameraView cameraView;
        private boolean mCapturingVideo =false;
        Fragment fragment;
        private static final String VIDEO_EXTENSION = ".mp4";
        private String mNextVideoAbsolutePath;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mirror, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            mContext = getContext();
            fragment = (MirrorFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mirror_frag");
            initViews(view);
    //        setWidthOfBottomContainer();

            up_arrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                }
            });

            iv_record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mCapturingVideo){
                        stopVideo();
                    }else{
                        captureVideo();
                    }

                }
            });

        }

        private void initViews(View view) {

            mLayout = (SlidingUpPanelLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
            mLayout.setAnchorPoint(0.5f);
            mMainLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
            frameContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.frame_video);
            cameraView = view.findViewById(R.id.camera);
            up_arrow = view.findViewById(R.id.up_arrow);
            iv_record = view.findViewById(R.id.record);
            cameraView.setLifecycleOwner(fragment.getViewLifecycleOwner());
            cameraView.mapGesture(Gesture.PINCH, GestureAction.ZOOM); // Pinch to zoom!
            toLandAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.view_to_landscape);
            toPortAnim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.view_to_portrait);
            orientationListener = new MirrorFragment.OrientationListener(mContext);
            childFragment = new DiscoveryFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_video, childFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            cameraView.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            cameraView.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            cameraView.destroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            orientationListener.enable();
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            orientationListener.disable();
        }

        @Override
        public void onMultiWindowModeChanged(boolean isInMultiWindowMode) {
            super.onMultiWindowModeChanged(isInMultiWindowMode);

        }

        private void getHeightWidth() {
           /* draggingPanelHeight = mLayout.getHeight();
           draggingPanelWidth = mLayout.getWidth();*/
            DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
            height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
            width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        }

        private class OrientationListener extends OrientationEventListener{
            final int ROTATION_0    = 1;
            final int ROTATION_90   = 2;
            final int ROTATION_180  = 3;
            final int ROTATION_270  = 4;

            private int rotation = 0;
            public OrientationListener(Context context) { super(context); }

            @Override public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {

                if( (orientation < 35 || orientation > 325) && rotation!= ROTATION_0){ // PORTRAIT
                    getHeightWidth();
                    rotation = ROTATION_0;
                    frameContainer.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
                }
                else if( orientation > 145 && orientation < 215 && rotation!=ROTATION_180){ // REVERSE PORTRAIT
                    getHeightWidth();
                    rotation = ROTATION_180;
                    frameContainer.startAnimation(toPortAnim);
                }
                else if(orientation > 55 && orientation < 125 && rotation!=ROTATION_270){ // REVERSE LANDSCAPE
                    getHeightWidth();
                    rotation = ROTATION_270;

                    //param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)width/2,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    frameContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)height/2,(int)width));

                    frameContainer.startAnimation(toLandAnim);

                }
                else if(orientation > 235 && orientation < 305 && rotation!=ROTATION_90){ //LANDSCAPE
                    getHeightWidth();
                    rotation = ROTATION_90;

                    //param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)width/2,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    frameContainer.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)height/2,(int)width));
                    frameContainer.startAnimation(toLandAnim);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

My problem is how to change the scrolling behaviour of recyclerView when it rotates to 90 degrees. Please find attached screenshot for reference.
[image]

[image]

If you see the attached screenshot then you can see when I rotated the frame container it rotated object inside it which is recylerView but in landscape it's scrolling like it scroll in portrait mode.

Comment: can you share snap shot of both view?